# Auto sync libraries referred by the Network users in Maven

Tags: maven, synchronization, repository, local

I have a Private Maven repository. I am looking for some solution to achieve the following. 
1. All the users in the network (or Domain) should first check whether the dependanciy looking for is available in private repo. If yes download to local using the private repo. If not, download the dependancies from central repo, while syncing the same with the Private Repo

2. An Automated way to re-arrange the dependancies to the latest version as long as there are not conflicts or errors occuring, so that there will be a minimal versions of the same libraries maintained in private and local repositories.

Comment: Are you using a repository manager ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first point is covered by Repository Managers as Nexus or Artifactory (as khmarbaise already said).

The second point is a bit vague to be answered, but in general, there is no automated mechanism to find out the "right" version of a dependency to work with your project(s), but there are Maven goals to update your dependencies to the lastest ones.